# Property '' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>' NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting following error when I'm trying to do simple res.send('hello') on app.get

```
Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>' NodeJS
```

I've made research and I found out that It is TS problem but the thing is I'm not using TS in this project.

Any suggestions?

Here is my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "postgres",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": " nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^4.0.4",
    "pg": "^8.2.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "^6.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

App.js

```
 const app = express();

app.get('/',(res,req)=>{
    res.send('Hello wolrd')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply got the order wrong. it's `req, res` not `res, req`

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that the first arg is req and the second res.

```js
app.get("/", (req, res)=> {
res.send("hallo wolrd");
});
```